# publicly available java secure web service

Tags: web-services, jax-ws

I am trying to write a web service client using Jax-ws for a secured webservice hosted by a third party. While doing so, I am facing a lot of issues and somehow wanted to find out if the issue is with my client or the hosted web service.

Do we have any publicly available and free secure web services on the internet? I can find many non secure services.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this URL:

http://www.webservicex.net/ws/wscatlist.aspx

... where you can find a bunch of published webservices.